# Querybuilder using variable

Tags: jquery, ajax, coldfusion, query-builder

I'm trying to use the http://querybuilder.js.org/index.html plugin with coldfusion. I'm stuck on this part:

```
$('.parse-sql').on('click', function() {
var target = $(this).data('target');
var result = $('#builder-'+target).queryBuilder('getSQL',$(this).data('stmt'));

if (result.sql.length) {
var test =result.sql;
alert(test);
$('#debugDiv').empty().append('waarde'+ test + '</div>');
bootbox.alert({
  title: $(this).text(),
  message: '<pre class="code-popup">' + format4popup(result.sql) + (result.params ? '\n\n' + format4popup(result.params) : '') + '</pre>'
});

}
});
```

What I'm trying to do is use the sql query in the result page. I have try some things like putting the result.sql in a variable test. Then display the TEST variable to a debugdiv, and that is working. The output is like "name LIKE('%Johnny%') AND ( category = 2 OR in_stock = 1 )".

Now the question: how can I use this in a result page? Must I export the variable with an AJAX request? Can someone help me a bit on this?

Thanks!

Comment: You can put the result of any javascript function into a hidden form field.  However, looking at your example, you might find it beneficial to use cfml instead of javascript to build your query.  At the very least, it's probably simpler, and you can better handle things like angle brackets and apostrophes.

Answer (score 0):

That is an easy function:

```
function format4popup(object) {
    return JSON.stringify(object, null, 2).replace(/</g, '&lt;').replace(/>/g, '&gt;')
}
```